# Google search engine shows incorrect page ranking for your site if you sign in Google?

Tags: seo, ranking, google-search

Most of us, have google account and usually,it sets to sign in automatically, when you enter to google homepage.

So if you are a webmaster and add your sites in google webmaster, be aware of something wrong in google search engine.

let suppose you have mysite.com and added it to google webmaster tools.
and your main keyword for finding your site is 'mykey'.
if you were logged in google and type 'mykey' in google search box, the page rank google shows for the 'mysite.com' is totally incorrect.

Google shows your page in one of the top pages (even in first poage or first place!) by mistake.
but if you log off your account and try again in search box, it will show you correct position of your site in ranking.

Let me know if it is a bug or natural way google works?

Comment: It's not a bug, since it's [well-documented](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=54041) (there may be additional docs).  This also isn't a question, and would make more sense on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be posing a concrete question to answer.

Comment: Thanks all... I edited my question...and i hope it is a Question now!
...i deleted all web history based on document you introduce me.
still, results are different if you sign in or out.
I am totally confused.

Answer (score 3):

Please visit [this](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=54041) site. It clearly explains how signed-in personalization of your search results work, and also how you can disable it (which is by disabling web history). Anyway, it is certainly not a bug.

Comment: Thanks all... I edited my question...and i hope it is a Question now! ...i deleted all web history based on document you introduce me. still, results are different if you sign in or out. I am totally confused.